# How to allocate memory for 3 band or monochrome image in Mex gateway function?

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, memory-management, mex

Usually I use below function to allocate memory for 3 band and monochrome image

```
/* For 3 band image */    
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dim_array, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

/*For monochrome image */
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(r,c,mxREAL);
```

that would be the case when we know the value of row(r), column(c) and dim_array. What if we don't know the value of r, c and dim_array?? It sounds stupid question...but what I am trying to do is I want to read an image from a file location. My Matlab function would be like

```
outputImage = imageRead('C:\abc\def\ghi.bmp');
```

I am just passing character string as input I cannot get the value of r, c and dim_array from the input, but we have to allocate memory for the output image in the main gateway function. How can we allocate the memory for this output image???

Comment: From Matlab, how will your function be called? eg. `result = myMexFunction(outputImage)` where outputImage is the result of imageRead and result is a double array of the same dimensions as outputImage?

Comment: Or is the goal of your mex function to read in an image itself from a file and return a three dimensional array representing the image back to MATLAB? `outputImage = myMexFunction(path)'; I don't fully follow what you're asking...

Comment: Yes, in matlab the function will be called as outputImage=myMexFunction(path). In my case mymexfunction is imageRead. You got it right i want to read an image itself from a file and return 3 dimensional array representing the image back to MATLAB. and the result should be the same dimensions as the output Image.

Comment: it will not be called as result = myMexFunction(outputImage). I basically want to implement function like the MATLAB inbuilt function imread(). The reason I want to do that is because we have our own image file format like  (.vip) which is not supported by the imread() function.

Answer (score 1):

At least in R2015b, this is how I think you do it. You may need to do a first pass through your file to determine `n_rows`, `n_cols` etc...

```
mwSize dims[3];      // for the dimensions of your numeric array
dims[0] = n_rows;
dims[1] = n_cols;
dims[2] = n_depth;   // 3 in case of 3-band, 1 in the case of monochrome

// call mxCreateNumeric to construct your array.
// as I understand mex works in 2015b, this should allocate memory for your array
mxArray *my_array = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

// get a pointer to your array. Requires a cast to (double *)
double *array_data = (double *) mxGetData(my_array);
```

And remember matrices in MATLAB are COLUMN MAJOR! That is, the my_array(i,j,k) entry would be accessed by `array_data[i + j*n_rows + k * (n_rows*n_cols)]`